# How to Unti Test Angular Components Depending on Firebase Service

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, unit-testing, mocking

I have a simple Create-User-Component that I want to unit test.

The component depends on an Auth Service with a few methods, like 'login, logout' etc.

The auth service imports both **AngularFireAuth** and **AngularFireStore**. It is the service that handles database interaction.

The problem is that I can't run my tests because I get a null injector error (shown in full bellow).

I want to mock out any database interaction, so that I can test the component in isolation.

I have tried various approaches, spying on the auth service, mocking its methods and even mocking the firestore dependency, but nothing gives me any progress on the particular error I am facing.

In the version of the code bellow, I inject a stubbed version of the auth service which is supposed to console log whenever one of its methods are called, but no logging occurs.

Why is this error coming and how do I mock out my firebase dependencies correctly so that I can test my components?

**Minimalized samples of my code**

**The component**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/core/services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-user',
  templateUrl: './create-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../credentials.component.scss', './create-user.component.scss'],
})
export class CreateUserComponent {

  public createUserForm: FormGroup;
  public message: string;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private auth: AuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    this.createUserForm = this.fb.group({
      firstName: ['some name', Validators.required],
      lastName: ['some name2', Validators.required],
      email: ['some.fake@mail.com', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])],
      password: ['password123', Validators.required]
    });
    this.message = '';
  }

  onSubmit(){
    if(!this.createUserForm.valid) {
      return;
    }
    this.auth.createNewUser(this.createUserForm.value)
    .then(async () => {
      this.router.navigate(['/credentials/verify-email']);
    })
    .catch(async (e) => console.error(e));
  }
}
```

**The test**

```js
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { FormBuilder, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/core/services/auth.service';
import { CreateUserComponent } from './create-user.component';

fdescribe('CreateUserComponent', () => {
  let component: CreateUserComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CreateUserComponent>;

  let authStub = {
    constructor: () => {console.log('constructor called')},
    login: () => {console.log('login called')},
    logout: () => {console.log('logout called')},
    createNewUser: () => {console.log('createNewUser called')},
  }


  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ CreateUserComponent ],
      providers: [ FormBuilder, 
        { provide: AuthService, usevalue: authStub},
        ],
      imports: [ FormsModule, AngularFireModule, AngularFirestoreModule ],
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CreateUserComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }));

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

**The service**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { UserRegistration } from '../types/user.types';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(
    private auth: AngularFireAuth,
    private firestore: AngularFirestore,
    private router: Router
  ) {
  }

  login(email: string, password: string): Promise<firebase.auth.UserCredential> {
    return this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }

  logout() {
    this.auth.signOut()
    .then(() => this.router.navigate(['/credentials/login']));
  }

  createNewUser(user: UserRegistration): Promise<void | firebase.auth.UserCredential> {
    return this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
    .then((res: firebase.auth.UserCredential) => {
      res.user && res.user.sendEmailVerification();
      this.firestore.collection('users')
      .add({
        firstName: user.firstName,
        lastName: user.lastName,
        email: res.user ? res.user.email : user.email,
        createdAt: new Date(),
      });
    });
  }
}
```

**The error I get**

> Chrome 90.0.4430.212 (Windows 10) CreateUserComponent should create FAILED
> Failed: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[AuthService -> AngularFireAuth -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options!
> error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ 'AuthService', 'AngularFireAuth', 'InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options', 'InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options' ] })
> NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[AuthService -> AngularFireAuth -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options -> InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options]:
> **NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken angularfire2.app.options!**
> at NullInjector.get (node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:11077:1)
> at R3Injector.get (node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:11243:1)
> at R3Injector.get (node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:11243:1)
> at injectInjectorOnly (node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:4728:1)
> at Module.ɵɵinject (node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:4732:1)
> at Object.AngularFireAuth_Factory [as factory] (node_modules/@angular/fire/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/angular-fire-auth.js:127:152)
> at R3Injector.hydrate (node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:11412:1)
> at R3Injector.get (node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:11232:1)
> at injectInjectorOnly (node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:4728:1)
> at ɵɵinject (node_modules/@angular/core/**ivy_ngcc**/fesm2015/core.js:4732:1)
> Error: Expected undefined to be truthy.
> at 
> at UserContext. (src/app/views/credentials/create-user/create-user.component.spec.ts:35:23)
> at ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:372:1)
> at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:287:1)
> Chrome 90.0.4430.212 (Windows 10): Executed 1 of 37 (1 FAILED) (skipped 36) (0.199 secs / 0.129 secs)
> **TOTAL: 1 FAILED, 0 SUCCESS**

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/testing-services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `usevalue` to `useValue` (capital V) and I think you should be good to go.

Comment: Wow, that did help. At least I'm getting new errors now. Thanks for your quick response. I find it a bit surprising that usevalue  does not trigger any intellisense or compile error.